# Knight Tour time limit exceeded

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, backtracking, knights-tour

Problem Statement:
Given a N*N board with the Knight placed on the first block of an empty board. Moving according to the rules of chess knight must visit each square exactly once. Print the order of each the cell in which they are visited.

```
Example:

Input : 
N = 8
Output:
0  59  38  33  30  17   8  63
37  34  31  60   9  62  29  16
58   1  36  39  32  27  18   7
35  48  41  26  61  10  15  28
42  57   2  49  40  23   6  19
47  50  45  54  25  20  11  14
56  43  52   3  22  13  24   5
51  46  55  44  53   4  21  12
```

**My code:**

```
def knightTravels(i,j,count,n,mat):

   if count == n**2:
      for list1 in mat:
         print(mat)
      print("====================")
      return 

   if i < 0 or j < 0 or i >= n or j >= n:
      return 

   if mat[i][j] != 0:
      return 

   mat[i][j] = count
   knightTravels(i-2,j-1,count+1,n,mat) # check
   knightTravels(i-2,j+1,count+1,n,mat) # check
   knightTravels(i-1,j-2,count+1,n,mat) # check
   knightTravels(i+1,j-2,count+1,n,mat) # check
   knightTravels(i+2,j-1,count+1,n,mat) # check
   knightTravels(i+2,j+1,count+1,n,mat) # check
   knightTravels(i-1,j+2,count+1,n,mat) # check
   knightTravels(i+1,j+2,count+1,n,mat) # check
   mat[i][j] = 0

def knightTour(n):
   mat = []
   for x in range(n):
      list1 = []
      for y in range(n):
         list1.append(0)
      mat.append(list1)
   i = j = count = 0
   knightTravels(i,j,count,n,mat)
knightTour(8)
```

**Problem:**
The code is throwing TLE, I am using backtracking the same way we solve rat in a maze problem. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: I suggest you start by reading this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour#Finding_tours_with_computers

Comment: @kaya3 but there must be a working code right?